# Pandas read_csv adds unnecessary " " to each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` file

(I am showing the first three rows here)

```
HEIGHT,WEIGHT,AGE,GENDER,SMOKES,ALCOHOL,EXERCISE,TRT,PULSE1,PULSE2,YEAR
173,57,18,2,2,1,2,2,86,88,93
179,58,19,2,2,1,2,1,82,150,93
```

I am using pandas `read_csv` to read the file and put them into columns.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path='~/Desktop/pulse.csv'

path=os.path.expanduser(path)
my_data=pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False, header=None, quoting = 3, delimiter=',')
print my_data
```

The problem is the first and last columns have " before and after the values.

Additionally I can't get rid of the indexes.

It might be making some silly mistake but I thank you for your help in advance

Comment: If remove `quoting = 3` how does it work?

Comment: In my opinion here is better if upload your file with 3 rows to gdocs, dropbox, another site and add link to question. Because your sample working nice. index_col=False means force not read first column to index, but dataframe always need some index, so is added default - `0,1,2...`.

Comment: if i remove quoting=3, there will not be columns, everything will fall into one column

Comment: I have uploaded the file, please see my comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution - use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with converting to `int`s and for remove `"` from columns names use [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('pulse.csv', quoting=3)

df = df.replace('"','', regex=True).astype(int)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
print (df.head())

   HEIGHT  WEIGHT  AGE  GENDER  SMOKES  ALCOHOL  EXERCISE  TRT  PULSE1  \
0     173      57   18       2       2        1         2    2      86   
1     179      58   19       2       2        1         2    1      82   
2     167      62   18       2       2        1         1    1      96   
3     195      84   18       1       2        1         1    2      71   
4     173      64   18       2       2        1         3    2      90   

   PULSE2  YEAR  
0      88    93  
1     150    93  
2     176    93  
3      73    93  
4      88    93
```

`index_col=False` means force not read first column to index, but dataframe always need some index, so is added default - `0,1,2...`. So here can be omit.

`header=None` should be removed because it force dont read first row (header of csv) to columns of `DataFrame`. Then also first row of data is header and numeric values are converted to strings.

`delimiter=','` should be removed too, because it is same as `sep=','` what is default parameter.

Comment: Here is the link to the excel file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm042izqdnq6bxw/pulse.csv?dl=0

Comment: thanks, column index are gone after (path, skipinitialspace = True, quoting = 3) as you suggested but the row index are still there.  Additionally, the problem of  " at each row is till there

Comment: Yes, solution is `df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.strip('"')`
`df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.strip('"')`

Comment: thanks, that removed the ' " ' for all rows except the first one (which is the column labels).  Is there a way to remove " from the first row too?  
Also the row index are still there.  How can I remove those?

Comment: for columns is necessary `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')`. And for remove first index column - is it impossible. But if dont need write first column to file use `df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`

Comment: I add final solution, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael is right - a pandas dataframe will always add indices. It's necessary.

try something like `df[0] = df[0].str.strip()` replacing zero with the last column.

before you do so, convert your csv to a dataframe - `pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path)`